# The difference between [*] and [*0] in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I know that `[*]` represents all vehicle, but what's the meaning of `[*0]` in OMNeT++?

```
*.node[*0].veinsmobility
*.node[*].veinsmobility
```

Comment: Do you know how regular expressions work?

Comment: Even though the syntax might be reminding some of a regular expression, it is not. OMNeT++ is using wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node[*0]` means the node whose index ends with `0`, i.e. `node[0]`, `node[10]`, `node[20]`, etc.
Reference: [Simulation Manual - 10.3.1 Using Wildcard Patterns](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:wildcards)